# how to concatenate 2 rows which have null values using listagg() function in oacle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

```
1234    NULL
1234    HELLO EVERYBODY
7895    NULL
```

I want the result to be like

```
1234  hello everybody,null
7895  null
```

I have tried using listagg(nvl(col, 'NULL')) in oracle,but it din't work.
Please help me with this.

Comment: why did you add `oracle10g` tag? `LISTAGG` is not available in 10g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 1234 ID,   NULL txt FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 1234 ID,   'HELLO EVERYBODY' txt FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 7895 ID,   NULL txt FROM dual)
  5  SELECT ID, LISTAGG(nvl(txt,'NULL'), ',')
  6            WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) list_agg
  7  FROM DATA
  8  GROUP BY ID
  9  /

                  ID LIST_AGG
-------------------- ------------------------------
                1234 HELLO EVERYBODY,NULL
                7895 NULL

SQL>
```

**EDIT** The `WITH` clause is to build the sample table for just demonstration. In your database you need to just rename the `DATA` with your `table name` and just execute the `select listagg..` query.

So, your final query would look like,

```
SELECT column_1, 
       LISTAGG(nvl(column_2,'NULL'), ',')
       WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_1) list_agg
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column_1
/
```

Comment: Thank u so much ,this works fine but the problem is that i have many records..so do i have to add union all ,that many times or is there any other way

Comment: That `UNION ALL` is a part of the `WITH` clause to build the sample table just to demonstrate. All you need to do is use the `select listagg query` and in place of `DATA` put your table name.